# Android Fragment popupMenu setOnMenuItemClickListener remplaces this

Tags: android, fragment

```
LinearLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.search2);//You can use other view as anchor
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);//View will be an anchor for PopupMenu
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu);
                Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
```

i use that in fragment and not activity..so  i have to change the two  "this" by other word
what i have to write in the two lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
//pass activity context in PopupMenu

PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity, view);

//imaplement fragment 

public class yourFragment extends Fragment implement MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{
//then set to popupMenu
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: first line shoud be write in the activity and not the fragment? and the rest of my code where i should put it? also i have erreur if i add implement menuitem.onMenuItem.....

Comment: "first line shoud be write in the activity and not the fragment? " ->you can use that in fragment."also i have erreur "->just Alt+ENTER on error message, it will show methods to implement.then  select all.@Ahmedfeki